# Cypress in GitHub Actions doesn't load CSS in a Vue CLI/Vuetify app

Tags: vuetify.js, cypress, github-actions, vue-cli

My cypress tests work great on my local machine (Windows) using chrome or headless, but when I try to run things in GitHub Actions environment (ubuntu-18.04), some of the tests pass, but most fail because the CSS doesn't get loaded, and elements are covered up, etc.
My stack includes a node.js Express server that serves a pre-built Vue CLI/Vuetify frontend as static content.

Anybody had a similar issue?

Thanks!